# FileSystemWatcher on network drive

Tags: android, vb.net, networking, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to watch the folder of my "Camera" on my phone. This is an android phone and connected to my PC with WebDAV server which allows to map the phone as a driver; it works fine. (The mounted folder is the "Camera" in DCIM.) When I take a picture it should trigger a sub in my program. Half year ago it was working fine, now I've continued to develop my program and it's not working. (I've just reinstalled my PC, I guess this is the only thing I've changed.) 
I read about a lot of trouble with filesystemwatcher over network drives.

- I've already tried it with one another phone and PC too, but I had no luck.
- It's working when I'm trying it with path "C:\"
- The program can see the mapped drive/ folder, it doesn't stop at the checking code.
- Also tried with copy and paste files to the given path instead of taking pictures...

Is there anything should I add or modify?

Here is my example code to illustrate...:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Public watchfolder As FileSystemWatcher
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim path As String
        path = "Z:\"
        watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
        watchfolder.Path = path

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) Then MsgBox("Wrong path.")

        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or IO.NotifyFilters.Attributes

        AddHandler watchfolder.Changed, AddressOf logchange
        AddHandler watchfolder.Created, AddressOf logchange
        AddHandler watchfolder.Deleted, AddressOf logchange
        AddHandler watchfolder.Error, AddressOf erroreventhandler 'I'm trying to read the error with this...

        watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub logchange(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
        MsgBox("This is the place where I'll call one sub in case of modification.")
    End Sub
    Sub erroreventhandler(sender As Object, e As ErrorEventArgs)
        'this is to stop the program in case of error... 
        ''it stops when I run the program on a mapped drive. (not on "C:\")
        '''I could provide the error texts, I don't really familiar with them...
        Stop
    End Sub
End Class
```